# Plant with leaves like Gladiolus and a tall flower spike with yellow flowers?

Tags: identification, flowers

[image]

This plant is growing in my daughter's garden. The leaves are similar to gladiolus and the flowers are along the stem the same way gladiola blossom are but they are tiny, cup shaped with 4 petals, pale yellow with a deeper yellow in the middle near the stamen and pistils.

Hopefully someone can tell me what this flower/plant is.

Comment: Pnuts, make an answer! It most certainly looks exactly like his...http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6f/Sisyrinchium_striatum02.jpg

Comment: Carol A - if you look more closely at the flowers in the photo you posted, you can see they have 6, not 4,  petals. Quite sure S. stratum that puts suggested is correct.

Comment: It is Sisyrinchium striatum - pnuts you should post it as an answer

Answer (score 2):

As noted by several people in the comments, it is [Sisyrinchium striatum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sisyrinchium_striatum).

Identifying characteristics are the sword-shaped leaves and the flower spike with clusters of pale yellow and gold six-petalled (not four) flowers.